# Como intercambiar posiciones en un array?

Tags: javascript

necesito hacer una funcion para cambiar las posiciones de un array, temporalmente. Tengo el siguiente array:

```
var grilla = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]
];
```

Quiero pasarle las posiciones por parametro:

```
function intercambiarPosicionesGrilla(filaPos1, columnaPos1, filaPos2, columnaPos2) {
}
```

Intente hacer esto pero no funciona:

```
function intercambiarPosicionesGrilla(filaPos1, columnaPos1, filaPos2, columnaPos2) {
    var x = (grilla[filaPos1][columnaPos1] = grilla[filaPos2][columnaPos2]);
}
```

Soy principiante en JS y estoy bastante perdida. No se me ocurre de que otra manera hacerlo. Me pueden ayudar?

Espero realizar esto:

```
intercambiarPosiciones(1, 1, 1, 2);
```

RESULTADO:

```
grilla = [[1, 2, 3],
         [4, 6, 5],
         [7, 8, 9]];
```

Comment: podrias agregar el resultado esperado en tu pregunta?

Comment: ahi lo agregue!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Conoces [los operadores de propagacion](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Spread_operator)?, bueno aqui un ejemplo simple de como usarlo basicamente le digo `[valorA,valorB] = [valorB,valorA]`, evitando declarar variables temporales el ejemplo a continuacion!
, para copiar el arreglo se usamos [lodash](https://docs-lodash.com/v4/clone-deep/) , debido a que todas las funciones nativas de JavaScript copian superficial los arreglos/objetos

```js
const grilla = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]
];
function intercambiarPosiciones(filaPos1, columnaPos1, filaPos2, columnaPos2) {
  const tmp = _.cloneDeep(grilla );
 //console.log(tmp);
  [tmp[filaPos1][columnaPos1],tmp[filaPos2][columnaPos2]] = 
  [tmp[filaPos2][columnaPos2],tmp[filaPos1][columnaPos1]]
  return tmp;

}

console.log(intercambiarPosiciones(1, 1, 1, 2));
console.warn(grilla)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Otra forma de resolverlo sería lo siguiente

```js
const grilla = [     [1, 2, 3],     [4, 5, 6],     [7, 8, 9] ];
const intercambiarPosicionesGrilla = (grilla, filaPos1, columnaPos1, filaPos2, columnaPos2) => {
 let temp_grilla = [...grilla.map(i => [...i])];
 temp_grilla[filaPos1][columnaPos1] = grilla[filaPos2][columnaPos2];
 temp_grilla[filaPos2][columnaPos2] = grilla[filaPos1][columnaPos1];
    return temp_grilla
}
const nuevaGrilla = intercambiarPosicionesGrilla(grilla, 1, 1, 1, 2);
console.log(nuevaGrilla);
```

Donde se pase el arreglo y los parámetros a una función que realice los cambios y me retorne un nuevo objeto transformado.

Comment: no uses el map , de hecho puedes hacer `temp_grilla  = grilla.slice();` o mas elegante `let temp_grilla = [...grilla];`

Comment: No hay de otra porque de no usar el map internamente sigues haciendo referencia al objeto original para indicar el contenido de cada posición del arreglo principal, y por tanto obtienes como salida `[ [ 1, 2, 3 ], [ 4, 6, 6 ], [ 7, 8, 9 ] ]`

Comment: sabias que las funciones de Javascript hacen una copia superficial de los arreglos/objetos?, en JavaScript no existe un metodo nativo de copiar un arreglo/objeto profundo, te invito a leer [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript) esta en el sitio en ingles pero te ayudara a comprender mas lo que digo

Comment: la idea es manipular solo el array grilla con una variable temporal, sin map. Alguna idea, sigo dandole la vuelta.